# Detail disclosure button not displaying in callout view

Tags: mapkit, ios7

How can I visualize detail disclosure button in callout view for an annotation view ?

The callout now show an info button, that is double-clickable to center the map, but no action on single click ( I performed a segue in my old code when disclosure button was tapped )

Answer (score 0):

I have identified the problem: it was the delegate method that was not called on tap, due to the fact I had added a couple of gesture recognizers to MKMapView , in this way  the MKMapView delegate method was not called. I have removed the gesture recognizer when the callout is shown and added again when the callout is hidden. I hope this cane help someone having my same problem.